# evaluate randomly generated math equation in string format and get answer out it

Tags: java

```
public class Test {

    static Random rand = new Random();
    String operators = "+-*/";

    public static char getRandomOperator() {
        return operators.charAt(rand.nextInt(operators.length()));
    }

    Random rand = new Random();
    int a = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
    int b = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;

    String equation = "";
    equation += a;
    equation += getRandomOperator();
    equation += b;
    equation += getRandomOperator();
    equation += c;
}
```

In this code consider i get equation= 2+3*4 which is in string format. how should i evaluate this and get answer in integer. i cant use javascript because i am using this code in android app.

Comment: what is `c` variable?

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is a expression evaluation problem. You can solve it by knowing precedence order of operators. This can go complex when parenthesis, factorials come into picture. You would need to use stack as well in order to solve these expressions. Answer can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-evaluation/).

Comment: Answer can be found somewhere<link>. Is not an answer in itself.

Comment: Thank you so much. I trued that code and modified little bit according to my need. And it works great.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of programmers are afraid of this kind of thing, and there are a *lot* of complicated ways to do it.

I am proud that I have done it enough times to have *finally* arrived at a pretty simple way to implement it.  Here is an implementation for your 4 operators, but it extends pretty easily to cover more precedence levels, unary operators, parentheses, and function as well.

The key is the signature of the `evaluateNext(int minPrec)` method, which provides an extremely convenient way to divide the problem up into equivalent subproblems:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Calculator {

    private static final Pattern TERM_AND_OP_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([^0-9a-zA-Z]*[0-9a-zA-Z\\.]+\\s*)([-+\\*\\/])");
    private static final HashMap<String, Integer> PRECS = new HashMap<>();
    {
        PRECS.put("+",0);
        PRECS.put("-",0);
        PRECS.put("*",1);
        PRECS.put("/",1);
    }

    String m_input;
    int m_currentPos;
    //points at the next operator, or null if none
    Matcher m_matcher;

    public synchronized double evalutate(String expression) throws Exception
    {
        m_input = expression;
        m_currentPos = 0;
        m_matcher = TERM_AND_OP_PATTERN.matcher(m_input);
        if (!m_matcher.find())
        {
            m_matcher = null;
        }
        try
        {
            return _evaluateNext(-1);
        }
        finally
        {
            m_input = null;
            m_matcher = null;
        }
    }

    //Evaluate the next sub-expression, including operators with
    //precedence >= minPrec
    private double _evaluateNext(int minPrec) throws Exception
    {
        double val;
        if (m_matcher == null)
        {
            val = Double.parseDouble(m_input.substring(m_currentPos).trim());
        }
        else
        {
            val = Double.parseDouble(m_matcher.group(1).trim());
        }

        while(m_matcher != null)
        {
            String op = m_matcher.group(2);
            //get and check precedence of the next operator
            Integer curPrec = PRECS.get(op);
            if (curPrec == null)
            {
                curPrec = 0;
            }
            if (curPrec<minPrec)
            {
                //our subexpression ends here
                return val;
            }
            //advance to next term/op
            m_currentPos = m_matcher.end();
            if (!m_matcher.find())
            {
                m_matcher = null;
            }
            switch(op)
            {
                case "+":
                    val += _evaluateNext(curPrec+1);
                    break;
                case "-":
                    val -= _evaluateNext(curPrec+1);
                    break;
                case "*":
                    val *= _evaluateNext(curPrec+1);
                    break;
                case "/":
                    val /= _evaluateNext(curPrec+1);
                    break;
            }
        }
        //found end of the expression
        return val;
    }


    public static void test(String expr) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.printf("%s = %f\n", expr, new Calculator().evalutate(expr));
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        test("8*2-1*4");
        test(" 8 * 2 - 1 * 4 ");
        test("-5 + -1 /2");
        test("223.3");
        test("223.3*2");
    }
}
```

Comment: nice;) +1 for creativity

Comment: I tried using this code but its function is not what i am expecting